# Can anyone compare US and Singaporean higher education systems?

Tags: united-states, singapore

On the surface, Singaporean university system looks exactly like US system.

Can anyone compare US and Singaporean higher education systems from their own experiences?

E.g.

- Quality of lectures
- Stress
- Cooperation/friendliness of professors/supervisors/TAs
- Campus culture
- Etiquette
- Creativity vs rote learning
- etc.

I am interested in Computer Science.

Comment: Given this quedtion here and this one, are you getting us to do your essay / presentation? https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107967/72855

Comment: @SolarMike, nope. If you are bothered, don't answer.

Answer (score 2):

- **Quality**. Comparable, and certainly not inferior. The curriculum is not substandard and its graduates are able to meet international standards. You can expect to learn everything a US undergraduate will also learn, up to minor differences that depend on the department's unique specialties (this does not apply to graduate studies). For example, Singapore undergraduates are capable of passing the GRE.
- **Stress**. Stress comes when you have high expectations for yourself and want to meet them. Accordingly, you can get as stressed or as not-stressed as you desire, by adjusting your expectations. This is no different from anywhere else in the world.
- **Professors/Supervisors/TAs**. No different from elsewhere in the world. Professors are in general an approachable lot.
- **Campus culture**. Within the class itself, the most important difference is that in Singapore, students don't participate that much during lectures. A lecturer who says something like "can anyone tell me what the significance of ____ theorem is" is likely to be met with silence. If students have problems which they need help from the professor, they're likely to approach the professor after class. Outside of class, attitudes tend to be pretty conservative. In the US a "free hugs" campaign might work; in Singapore, nobody is going to participate. You might have trouble making friends since you'll probably have to initiate the conversation (especially if you're not Chinese).
- **Etiquette**. What is regarded as polite is generally transferable across cultures. Because Singapore is a mish-mash of cultures, Singaporeans are pretty accommodating, and you'll probably have no problems.
- **Creativity vs. rote learning**. You already have [a question about this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/107967/rote-learning-in-south-east-asia).

If you're thinking about studying in Singapore, here're a few more factors to consider:

- Singapore is one of the world's safest countries. Crime rates are extremely low. Every now and then there will be mass shootings in the US, including at university campuses, but those never happen in Singapore.
- Singapore's public infrastructure is one of the world's best. Everywhere is easy to get to in Singapore. The high population density makes public transport sometimes crowded especially during rush hour, but it also means you will generally be able to e.g. find food at 11pm at night, get top-class medical care, and enjoy all sorts of entertainment. Singapore internet speeds are some of the [world's fastest](http://www.speedtest.net/reports/singapore/).
- Singapore's university infrastructure is also excellent. In fact after having visited lots of universities, including several of the world's best (by THE / QS / ARWU ranking), I've not seen anything that beats Singapore's infrastructure. The lecture halls are well-equipped, well-maintained, and modern; the campus buses run frequently including on weekends; the libraries are stocked with floors upon floors of books, etc. It's as though the Singapore government knows its universities are not yet regarded as among the best in the world, but they're determined to make sure they have the facilities to get there.
- Singaporean universities apparently [operate with a Bell curve](http://blog.nus.edu.sg/provost/2012/01/20/the-bell-curve/comment-page-2/). That is, the average grade is a B. This might come as a culture shock if you're used to everyone in a class scoring 80+.
- Staff-to-student ratio is relatively poor. There are tens of thousands of students.

Comment: Bell curve alone is enough to deter prospective students.

Comment: @why I think people go to college to pursue knowledge, grade is the byproduct.

Comment: @scaaahu obviously you don't know the Asian culture, and Singapore's 'afraid to lose' mentality.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Why do you connect 'afraid to lose' mentality to grading? I thought they would give students sweet grades if they want to attract students

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus hahaha :D AMEN on that, also xenophobia!